# c++ reference as shorthand to private variable

Tags: c++, reference

I have a habit of using references as a shorthand to internal variables which would otherwise be more cumbersome to access, for example like so:

```
class Vec3
{
    double v[3];

public:

    // .x, .y and .z element access operators for convenience.
    double& x;
    double& y;
    double& z;

    Vec3() : x(v[0]), y(v[1]), z(v[2])
    {

    }
}
```

This way, I can for example do this:

```
main
{
    Vec3 v;
    v.x = 1;
    v.y = 2;
    v.z = 3;
}
```

So far everything works perfectly. Now, it so happens that this very Vec3 class is nested inside an another. I would like to have direct access to Vec3.v[0] from the higher class like so:

```
struct Node
{
    double &x;
    Vec3 v;
    Node() : v(Vec3()), x(v.x) {}
};
```

such that Node.x would actually be Node.v.v[0] and I would be able to do this:

```
main
{
    Node n;
    n.v.x = 1;
    n.x = 2;
    std::cout << n.v.x << " " << n.x;
}
```

but unfortunately no. The output I should be seeing is

```
2 2
```

but what I really see is

```
1 2
```

As you can see, I am attempting to point the reference x in 
the initialization list of the Node constructor to the reference v.x of Vec3, and I even initialize and call the constructor of Vec3 explicitly before. Still, n.x seems to be referencing something else. Perhaps this way it would work

```
Node() : x(v.v[0]) {}
```

but v.v is private and I really want it to stay that way.

How can I make this work the way I intend without making v.v public?

Comment: What is this `main`? Did you mean `int main()`?

Comment: You do not initialize `v` before `x` just by changing the order in the initializer list, because the order of members in the struct declaration determines initialization order.

Comment: If you are providing `public` references to `private` data, you are effectively making that data `public`.   The only difference is that one means of accessing that data is `public` (the reference) and the other (by the actual member) is `private`.   In any event, all you need to do is use public inheritance, rather than containment.

Comment: This is a totally needles redundancy of data. A no go. Please examine the size of the class without reference, versus the class with references.

Comment: @Peter: as long as the reference is same cv as the data, yes. However, if it's, for example `const T&` that gets initialized to `T&`, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Public inheritance is actually a really good suggestion. Somehow I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `Node` struct. Class initialization order is not dependent on order of initializations specified in cosntructor, but rather on order of declaration of variables.

You are basicaly initializing `double&` with some weird, unitialized stuff, which is undefined behaviour.

Change order of declarations to

```
struct Node
{
    Vec3 v;
    double &x;
    Node() : v(Vec3()), x(v.x) {}
};
```

and you will be fine.

Comment: @Motionbit It is not necessary to write *thank you* comment. Better is to accept my answer.